# How do I retrieve data in SQL from a previous date in the pass 12 months in a WHERE CLAUSE using the date and time functions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How do I retrieve data in SQL from a previous date in the pass 12 months in a WHERE CLAUSE using the date and time functions?

```
--ServiceDates in past 12 months
WHERE YEAR(CONVERT(DATE, CLM_FROM_DT)) = 2016.
```

Comment: Are you looking for one year from today fixed dates?

Comment: which datepart are you trying to filter?

Comment: Sorry I added the wrong logic. This is the logic. WHERE YEAR(CONVERT(DATE, CLM_FROM_DT)) = 2016. I am only going back 12 months from 3/31/2017 to 3/31/2016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of these should work depending on what you need.

For any date range:

```
WHERE CLM_FROM_DT BETWEEN '20160331' AND '20170331'
```

If you are looking for 1 year back from current date:

```
WHERE CLM_FROM_DT>DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
```

If you are looking for 1 year back from specific date (2017-3-31) as per your comment:

```
WHERE CLM_FROM_DT>DATEADD(year,-1, '20170331')
```

Comment: I am looking for 1 year back from 2017-3-31 instead of current date in which i don't think i need to use GETDATE().

Comment: Well you could simply use the dateadd function on that starting point if you wanted to.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: `WHERE CLM_FROM_DT BETWEEN '20160331' AND '20170331'` will select one year + 1 day, if that column is a `DATE`.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Good point. My answer was based on the dates in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
[...]
WHERE CLM_FROM_DT BETWEEN DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```